# JQuery UI slider setting multiple input values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, input, slider

I am trying to get multiple values to change while sliding the JQuery UI slider. Basically changing 3 different values based on the slider's number. 
In this case I'm using a range of $100,000 to $2,000,000.  Then I want to calculate 3 different values depending on the position of the slider.
For the first value I want to get 6% - (2.7%+ $2799).
The second value would be 6% - $5299.
And the third value would be 6% - $3799
This is what I have so far:

```
<div id="slider">
<div id="slider-min">$100,000</div>
<div id="slider-max">$2,000,000</div>
</div>
<input id="amount" readonly type="text">
<div class="options-wrap">
<input id="result1" readonly type="text">
<input id="result2" readonly type="text">
<input id="result3" readonly type="text">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  range: 'min',
  value: 100000,
  min: 100000,
  max: 2000000,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
   $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + addCommas(ui.value.toString()));
  }
});
$('#amount')
.val( "$" + addCommas($("#slider").slider("value")));
///  Need to add a function(s) that would change the values of
///  the following selectors $('#result1'),$('result2') and $('result3')
///  based on the position of the slider with the calculation stated above.
function addCommas(nStr)
{
nStr += '';
x = nStr.split('.');
x1 = x[0];
x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
}
return x1 + x2;
}
});
```

I have tried different ways to get those 3 values to change while sliding the slider, but I've frustratingly failed on every attempt.  I gotta admit I'm no expert and I greatly respect those who have better knowledge on this field.  Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQUERY:

```
$(function () {
$("#slider").slider({
    range: 'min',
    value: 100000,
    min: 100000,
    max: 2000000,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val("$" + addCommas(ui.value));
        $("#result1").val("$" + addCommas(Math.round(ui.value*.06 - (.027+ 2799))));
        $("#result2").val("$" + addCommas(Math.round(ui.value*.06 -5299)));
        $("#result3").val("$" + addCommas(Math.round(ui.value*.06 -3799)));
    }
});
$('#amount')
    .val("$" + addCommas($("#slider").slider("value")));
///  Need to add a function(s) that would change the values of
///  the following selectors $('#result1'),$('result2') and $('result3')
///  based on the position of the slider with the calculation stated above.
function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

});

Research: http://jsfiddle.net/eqnLc9fg/1/

Comment: You're a life saver. You surely made my day. Thank you :) +1